# How to create common object of a class to use in all methods Of TestNG class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package com.test;

import org.testng.Reporter;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import utility.BaseClass;

import com.pages.LoginPageObjects;

public class UnderTest extends BaseClass

{

    @Test(description = "Email login")
    public void f()
    {
        Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
        LoginPageObjects lpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);
        lpage.click_signin_link();
        lpage.enter_uid("test@gmail.com");
        lpage.click_submit(); 
    }

    @Test(description = "fb login")
    public void fe() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
        LoginPageObjects lpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);
        lpage.click_fb_button();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }


}
```

The test runs well if I create object separately in both the methods. When declared in @BeforeTest it is not working. How can I reduce the reuse of that statement?

Comment: Show us the trials of how you created `@BeforeTest` method. Because "not working" is not enough :)

Comment: @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
      LoginPageObjects lpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, 
      LoginPageObjects.class);

 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to `LoginPageObjects` instance, you have to create it as `class variable`. It will be accessible for all methods within your class.

Then, initialize this variable in `@BeforeTest` annotation.

```
public class UnderTest extends BaseClass {
    private LoginPageObjects lpage;

@BeforeTest
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       lpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObjects.class);
   }

@Test(description = "Email login")
public void f()
{
    Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
    lpage.click_signin_link();
    lpage.enter_uid("test@gmail.com");
    lpage.click_submit(); 
}

@Test(description = "fb login")
public void fe() throws InterruptedException
{
    Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
    lpage.click_fb_button();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

}
```

Comment: @Rick can you make sure that `@BeforeTest` method ran? Add `Reporter.log("set up", true);` inside `setUp()` method

Comment: ===Set up===
===Browser session started===
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73) on port 20675
Only local connections are allowed.
Feb 07, 2018 6:59:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
===dude===
===dude===
===Browser session end===

Comment: Yeah Before test method ran before the browser session

Comment: @Rick Please provide `BaseClass` implementation. Looks like the problem is with providing `driver` to `UnderTest` class

Comment: public class BaseClass {
 public WebDriver driver;
 
  @BeforeClass
 public void setup() throws InterruptedException
 {
  Reporter.log("===Browser session started===", true);
  driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome","https://dude.com/login"); 
  Thread.sleep(5000);
 }
 
  AfterClass
 public void close()
 {
  driver.quit();
  Reporter.log("===Browser session end===", true);
 }
}

Comment: @Rick you get the `NullPointerException` because `setUp()` method is run BEFORE starting a session. Which means, `WebDriver` was NOT initialized.

Comment: How can I make setup method to run after starting a session?

Comment: @Rick It's because `@BeforeTest` runs faster than `@BeforeClass` method.

Try to change `@BeforeClass` to `@BeforeSuite`

Comment: The order in TestNG is:

`@BeforeSuite` 
`@BeforeTest` 
`@BeforeClass` 
`@BeforeMethod` 
`@Test` 
`@AfterMethod` 
`@AfterClass` 
`@AfterTest` 
`@AfterSuite`

Comment: @Rick Accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following code...

```
package com.test;

import org.testng.Reporter;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import utility.BaseClass;

import com.pages.LoginPageObjects;

public class UnderTest extends BaseClass

{

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
     LoginPageObjects lpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, 
     LoginPageObjects.class);

}
    @Test(description = "Email login")
    public void f()
    {
        Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
        lpage.click_signin_link();
        lpage.enter_uid("test@gmail.com");
        lpage.click_submit(); 
    }

    @Test(description = "fb login")
    public void fe() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Reporter.log("===dude===", true);
        lpage.click_fb_button();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }


}
```

Comment: I won't work. You created an instance of `LoginPageObjects` within `setUp()` method. It won't be accessible for `f()` and `fe()` methods, unless you'll make a `LoginPageObjects` as instance variable

Comment: @Rick Check my answer